# Jmeter- CSV Data Config- POST body

Tags: csv, post, jmeter

I am passing username and password to post body in HTTP request through CSV data config. but in view results tree tab, the request is getting like this.

```
      View Results Tree:

      POST data:
     {"email":"<EOF>","password":"<EOF>"}

    my HTTP request:
    {"email":"${username}","password":"${password}"}
```

why is EOF passing to it? can someone provide a solution for this, please?

I have followed steps from the  below stack overflow  question no. 27634885 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27634885/in-jmeter-what-would-be-syntax-of-parameters-in-body-data-section-of-http-reque).

Answer (score 0):

EOF stands for `End of File`.

Did you check the `jmeter.log` in `%JMETER_HOME%/bin` folder.

Ensure that you have correct absolute file path to the csv file & you have enough data in the CSV file.

You can set the 'Recycle on EOF?' to true if you want to re-use the data again & again.

Comment: I have given proper path., i am using 5 users only

Comment: How many records you have? Is it happening for all the users?

Comment: I have 5 users. , for all the users, I am getting the same error.

Comment: put your CSV in the same folder where is located your .jmx and in the csv data file, put only the name of your csv file.

Comment: @RaviVaranasi, Can you upload your .jmx file & csv file removing any sensitive data?

Comment: aleix - i have placed both files in single folder. it is working fine now.