# Need to build large Json Request using "CSV Data Set Config" in Jmeter

Tags: json, csv, jmeter, performance-testing

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637247/12820240

I saw above answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637247/12820240) from another question, 
but my questions is,
Is there anyway that that I can build large Json Request by adding comma separated with new data? Would appreciate for any help/direction. 
for ex:

```
{
{
  "phoneNo": "9998885551",
  "lastName": "john25",
  "email": "azp25@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "ricky25",
  "mobileNo": "9820420420"
},
{
  "phoneNo": "9998885552",
  "lastName": "john26",
  "email": "azp26@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "ricky25",
  "mobileNo": "9820420421"
},
{
  "phoneNo": "9998885553",
  "lastName": "john27",
  "email": "azp27@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "ricky27",
  "mobileNo": "9820420422"
}

...

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Given your CSV file looks like:

```
9998885551,john25,azp25@gmail.com,ricky25,9820420420
9998885552,john26,azp26@gmail.com,ricky26,9820420421
```

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which body you want to generate
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def body = []
   new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().each { line ->
       def entry = [:]
       def values = line.split(',')
       entry.put('phoneNo', values[0])
       entry.put('lastName', values[1])
       entry.put('email', values[2])
       entry.put('firstName', values[3])
       entry.put('mobileNo', values[4])
       body.add(entry)
   }
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(body).toPrettyString(),'')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
3. That's it, the JSR223 PreProcessor will generate the request body out of the CSV file

   [image]

References:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)